# Create a new sprite every time a touch ends

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am playing around trying to learn swift and I am trying to have a brick sprite placed every time a person's touch ends. I'm new and not quite sure of if or how this is possible with spriteKit. I would like to have the brick interact with physics so if there is another way to do this without creating new sprites that would work as well

Answer (score 0):

Just add the method `touchesEnded` to your class, create a new SpriteNode and add it to your scene. Something like this:

```
func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   let yourNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick.png") //or the name of the brick texture file, if you have one
   yourNode.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) 
   self.addChild(yourNode)
}
```

Here we added the node to (100,100), but you could add it to the location of the touch, adding  this inside the method:

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    yourNode.position = location
}
```

Remember to import `SpriteKit` to your class.

Comment: Oh, okay. In this case, try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39020344/11535394 It is in Swift 3.0 but the idea is the same, and probably only a few things changed for Swift 5.

Comment: It probably would. You just have to check if the touch location is inside the position of any of the array's nodes (use `.contains()` for that), then move that specific node.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I never have been much good at asking questions and the problem is that I would like to be able to use the nodes outside of that func. For example, I want to be able to tap on it and drag to change its position and I can't access the variable from the touches moved func. Thank you again!                                  EDIT: I am thinking of creating a global arrayList and a function that adds brick sprites to that arraylist and have the touches functions simply refer to a specific item in the arraylist, would that work?